# Sticky notes editable after flattening

Tags: c#, itext, desktop-application

I want to flatten an annotated PDF document.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dtnFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
    try
    {
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, fs, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.AnnotationFlattening = true;
        stamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;
        stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
        isFlattened = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isFlattened = false;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except that I cannot flatten the sticky note popup window. I want either flatten the popup or place the sticky note content in the same location.

Comment: I think your only option is to [recompile iTextSharp on your own with similar changes from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22550077/231316).

Comment: sticky note popup window will not flatten i have tried a lot.